# How to use source command within Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I recently rewrite bash execution command into Jenkins pipeline. The old code is like

```
...
source environment.sh
//Build
//Test
...
```

Now I use pipeline script to wrap the command, like this

```
sh '''
    ...
    source environment.sh
    //Build
    //Test
    ...
'''
```

However, I got an error, as`.../.jenkins/script.sh: line 9: source: environment.sh: file not found`. When I try to `less environment.sh`, it display correctly. So I suspect something wrong with `source command` within `sh wrap`.

Before using pipeline, `source environment.sh` command is working fine in shell execution. So source is install at Jenkins server, it seems pipeline script don't know what is the source command.

How could I do to run source command within sh wrapped block?

Comment: To debug use `echo $pwd; ls .`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Replace `source environment.sh` with

```
. ./environment.sh
```

Please note there is a space after first dot.

Comment: This one works. I don't need use absolute path anymore. Thank you

Answer (score 16):

`source` is a `bash`/`ksh`/etc extension, provided as a more "substantial" synonym for `.`.

In `sh`, you need to use `.` in case the underlying shell is one (such as `dash`) that does not support the command `source`.

```
sh '''
    ...
    . ./environment.sh
    //Build
    //Test
    ...
'''
```

Comment: I suppose triple quotes is the syntax in pipeline script, which identify multiple lines command. And I tried use `.` instead of `source`, however, no luck on that. Similar error throws `/.jenkins/script.sh: line 9: .: environment.sh: file not found`

Comment: Ah, missed that this wasn't just a shell script. (Although that should have been obvious, sorry.) It looks like the real problem is that Jenkins has a different working directory than your original script. Using an absolute path (instead of just `environment.sh`) should work.

Comment: Thank you, with absolute path, it works. Still, it's weird that linux cannot find the file

Comment: @Neil You have to put ' ./' in first: `. ./environment.sh`. It worked for me.

Comment: Fixed; I always forget that `.` uses path lookup if there is no `/` in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

If someone want to execute the script with source only solution is to change "Shell executable" to bash in ->Manage Jenkins->Configure System

Answer (score 1):

`. ./script.sh` it works fine!, but you can also do:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
      source /path/to/script.sh
                    
   '''
```

**IMPORTANT!**: Note that `#!/bin/bash` is the first line in the script